# Tableau Box Plot has Data outside Bounds

Tags: tableau-api, boxplot

This [tutorial](https://youtu.be/dUE7LvBSMMQ) explains how to create Box plot in Tableau

[First part of tutorial](https://youtu.be/dUE7LvBSMMQ?t=2m41s) shows how to create below graphic, where the data points are within the box plot

[image]

[Second part of tutorial](https://youtu.be/dUE7LvBSMMQ?t=3m39s) uses Tableau's Box Plot function to create below graphic. Note how some points are located well past the Box Plot.

How is this a normal box Plot? Or is the video wrong? Please clarify

[image]

Comment: Why don't you ask the person who made the video? Without knowing the underlying data, its hard to give you a precise answer. Also, why not just try it on your own and see how it works?

Comment: Try reading the Wikipedia article on boxplots. The answer you seek is there, and in any decent book that explains boxplots.

Comment: There are several ways to define boxplots. The versions differ in what proportions of the data are covered by the parts of the boxplot. In one common one the "box" covers the central 50% of the data (the IQR) and the "whiskers" cover the range from the bottom 5% to the top 95% of the data. There will always be outliers with this definition. Tableau default is that whiskers cover 1.5 times the IQR (but you can choose the whole range of the data if you want).

Comment: @matt_black Thank you, I shall look into this further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tableau creates their boxplots by default putting whiskers at 1.5 times the inter-quartile range (IQR). Basically, this method excludes what it considers to be outliers. To adjust see Step 10 in the link below

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/buildexamples_boxplot.html

Comment: Thank you, I shall look into this further